# static and responsive footer bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i made a simple page to review a video with some icons, and footer at the bottom.
I added footer class bootstrap to it, but i still don't see the footer on the same place in different screens

this is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/full.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body class="full">
<div class="container">


<br>

<p class="text-center" id="paragraph">Please Make Sure Your Sound Is Turned Up!  Please wait up to 10 seconds for this video to load.  Thank You!</p>
<center>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true" id="face"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true" id="twitter"></i>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="mybutton">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="">
<input type="image" src="images/order.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</center>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="footer">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="disclaimer.htm">Disclaimer</a></li> 
      <li><a href="earnings.htm">Earnings</a></li>
      <li><a href="privacy.htm">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="tos.htm">Tos</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is the CSS :

```
.full {
    background: url('../images/bg2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

#border{
     max-height: 400px;
     align:center;
     border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000
}
#paragraph{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:red;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}


#face {
  color:#3b5998;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
#twitter {
  color:#0084b4;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

The problem that the footer keep change it's place by changing sizes of screens.

Comment: don't use `<center>` tag, do it with css instead

Comment: @jakob i know but this isn't which causing the problem

Comment: I know, that's why I just commented. `<center>` is not supported in HTML5. Also, it would be better to call for js scripts at the end of page, not in the middle. And you have one extra closing `</div>` after jquery call.

Comment: @Cwalavice what do you mean by `footer keep change it's place by changing sizes of screens`? Where do you see your footer on what breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You use default bootstrap navigation in footer and class `collapse` means that navigation will be hidden on lower resolutions because bootstrap then adds responsive menu.

So if you want to see navigation on all resolutions remove `collapse` class from it.
Like this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="footer">
```

**Update**

For footer fix check example here https://jsfiddle.net/xuhL8v4v/

Comment: i removed the collapse and now footer available in all sizes, but still not static at the bottom like this image : http://i.imgur.com/DjjnBKY.png

Comment: thanks, it's worked for me. can you tell me if need how to make it sticky ??

Comment: this is sticky.. do you mean fixed?

Answer (score -1):

delete the div just uder the script and take the script below the footer so the final code looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/full.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body class="full">
<div class="container">


<br>

<p class="text-center" id="paragraph">Please Make Sure Your Sound Is Turned Up!  Please wait up to 10 seconds for this video to load.  Thank You!</p>
<center>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true" id="face"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true" id="twitter"></i>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="mybutton">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="">
<input type="image" src="images/order.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</center>
</div>



<div class="footer">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="footer">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="disclaimer.htm">Disclaimer</a></li> 
      <li><a href="earnings.htm">Earnings</a></li>
      <li><a href="privacy.htm">Privacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="tos.htm">Tos</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wait.what you want to do the link you provided above is fine.

Comment: This is just what I told in comments below question. It is not solution for problem.